# The use of "not" and "don't"

Tags: word-usage

"Why people like art?" is  a question for ESL students.

I tried to answer the question and wrote several possibilities, because I am confused by "or not" and "don't". Could you please correct them?

1. "I don't know how it happens. It happens by itself. You like it or not, you either understand or not."
2. "I don't know how it happens. It happens by itself. You like it or you don't like it. You either understand it or you don't understand it."
3. "I don't know how it happens. It happens by itself. You either like it or not, understand it or not."

Comment: "Why people like art" isn't a question.  It isn't even a sentence.  It is a noun phrase.

Comment: Thank you. But regarding the sentences, are they correct?

Comment: (2) and (3) are better than (1) - _You like it or not_ needs _either_ as in (3).

Comment: In the first sentence I will add "either", remove the second "either" and add "it". So it will be the same sentence as #3.